# Entity Framework mysterious error

Tags: entity-framework

Please help. I don`t understand why from my entity context

```
var stagesExist = context.WfwDocumentWorkStages
   .Any(it => it.Enabled && it.ExecutionId == execution.Id
   && it.Level == execution.Level && it.ResultId == null);
```

value stagesExist is false
But

```
var stages = context.WfwDocumentWorkStages.Where(it => it.Enabled 
   && it.ExecutionId == execution.Id
   && it.Level == execution.Level).ToList();
bool stagesExist = stages.Any(it=>it.ResultId == null);
```

value stagesExist is true??

Comment: Please try changing the last clause in the first implementation to `&& it.ResultId == null`. I think you are capturing `it` again with a different value...

Comment: it's just a typo here

Answer (score 0):

Model:

```
public partial class WfwDocumentWorkScheme : EnabledEntity
{
    public WfwDocumentWorkScheme()
    {
        this.WfwExecutionEvents = new List<WfwExecutionEvent>();
    }

    public int ExecutionId { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public int? RoleId { get; set; }
    public string CoordinatorSid { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? Date { get; set; }
    public int? ResultId { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Coordinator { get; set; }
    public virtual EmployeeRole EmployeeRole { get; set; }
    public virtual WfwEventResult WfwEventResult { get; set; }
    public virtual WfwDocumentExecution WfwDocumentExecution { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<WfwExecutionEvent> WfwExecutionEvents { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping

```
public class WfwDocumentWorkSchemeMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<WfwDocumentWorkScheme>
{
    public WfwDocumentWorkSchemeMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.CoordinatorSid)
            .HasMaxLength(46);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("WfwDocumentWorkSchemes");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        this.Property(t => t.ExecutionId).HasColumnName("ExecutionId");
        this.Property(t => t.Level).HasColumnName("Level");
        this.Property(t => t.RoleId).HasColumnName("RoleId");
        this.Property(t => t.CoordinatorSid).HasColumnName("CoordinatorSid");
        this.Property(t => t.Date).HasColumnName("Date");
        this.Property(t => t.ResultId).HasColumnName("ResultId");
        this.Property(t => t.Comment).HasColumnName("Comment");
        this.Property(t => t.Enabled).HasColumnName("Enabled");

        // Relationships
        this.HasRequired(t => t.Coordinator)
            .WithMany(t => t.WfwDocumentWorkSchemes)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.CoordinatorSid);
        this.HasRequired(t => t.WfwDocumentExecution)
            .WithMany(t => t.WfwDocumentWorkSchemes)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.ExecutionId);
        this.HasRequired(t => t.WfwEventResult)
            .WithMany(t => t.WfwDocumentWorkSchemes)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.ResultId);
        this.HasOptional(t => t.EmployeeRole)
            .WithMany(t => t.WfwDocumentWorkSchemes)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.RoleId);
    }
}
```

Result model contains virtual List

```
public class WfwEventResult : EnabledEntity
{
    public WfwEventResult()
    {
        this.WfwExecutionEvents = new List<WfwExecutionEvent>();
        this.WfwDocumentWorkSchemes = new List<WfwDocumentWorkScheme>();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<WfwExecutionEvent> WfwExecutionEvents { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<WfwDocumentWorkScheme> WfwDocumentWorkSchemes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It would be better to modify your original question rather than to put this as an answer.

Comment: Thank`s! next time do

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line in your mapping:

```
this.HasRequired(t => t.WfwEventResult)
```

You are effectively telling the EF that the associated FK column will never be `null` (although you've made it `int?` and have records with `null` value). Remember that EF uses metadata information when building SQL queries, and in this case I guess the query optimizer decides that this query will never return records (similar to `.Where(it => false)`) and generates a fake SQL query you see.

Shortly - make sure you always provide the correct information to EF. In this case, change the above to

```
this.HasOptional(t => t.WfwEventResult)
```

and you'll see a different (real) query and get a correct results.