# Creating an anonymous object depending on parameters

Tags: c#

To simplify the problem, I suppose that I have a method with two boolean parameters getParamA and getParamB.

```
public JsonResult MyMethod(bool getParamA, bool getParamB)
```

Is There a way like a ternary operator or something to say if getParamA == true and getParamB == false for example, I create an anonymous object like this :

```
//this is an entityframework query 
var result = entityContext.MyTable.Select(r=> new 
{ 
      paramA = r.paramA // because getParamA = true
      // don't create paramB because getParamB is false  
});
```

I know it is easy to implement this using two parameters (using if else condition) but things are getting complicated if we have more than 5 paramters (because you need to do all the testing)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but it isn't really efficient code. It makes your code a complete mess:

```
.Select( r => getParamA && getParamB
              ? (object)new { A = r.A, B = r.B }
              : (getParamA ? new { A = r.A }
                           : (getParamB ? new { B = r.B }
                                        : null
                             )
                )
       );
```

A better option might be the `ExpandoObject`, which uses a dictionary internally to store its properties and values.

```
dynamic eo = new ExpandoObject();

if (getParamA)
{
    eo.A = r.A;
}

if (getParamB)
{
    eo.B = r.B;
}
```

Comment: Well, you are asking if it is possible, the answer is yes. Should you do it? No.

Comment: @MehdiSouregi `ExpandoObject` then?

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to implement it within the lambda expression above?

Comment: How would you create that expando object in expression (worse -
 this expression also represents a database query)?

Comment: @Evk What do you mean? Which query?

Comment: `entityContext.MyTable.Select(r=> new ... )` < this one. While not specified explicitly - you can safely assume that is some entity framework or other ORM query, I think.

Comment: I think if I want to use the ExpandoObject i should get all the columns and after that I do the testing, I mean there is no way I can only get the parameters that I want.

Comment: @Evk Oh, yes. That is possible indeed. Then he has to materialize first, and then `Select`.

Comment: @PatrickHofman, so there is no way I can get only the columns that I want ?

Comment: With EF? Then you have to build the expression yourself depending on your parameters.

Comment: Something like what is demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35346630/993547).

Comment: Wow, as the answerer said in your link, the implmentation is too overcomplicated :p so I am going to get all the columns and for my case it happens to be that all the parameters on the entry are the exact same parameters on the table. I can not use ExpandoObject for my case because it is not serializable, so maybe i am going to use an IDictionnary

Comment: @MehdiSouregi ExpandoObject is serializable to json (for example by JSON.NET). Besides - it already implements `IDictionary<string, object>`.