# Passing predicate to LINQ where clause

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

Hey I have following code:

```
    Func<Assoc, bool> predicate = (x) => 
    (
        !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(version) ? x.Version.Contains(version) : x.Version != null

    );

    var assocs = _context.Assoc
                    .Where(x => x.Model == model)
                    .Where(predicate)
                    ;
```

But it doesn't work. If I try to execute this server gives me Internal Server Exception but if I change this to

```
var assocs = _context.Assoc
      .Where(x => x.Model == model)
      .Where(x => x.Version.Contains(version))
;
```

it works as I expect.

Why is that?

Is it possible to get preview of Linq generated query?

Comment: EF cannot interpret your code you have to build an Expression, which can be translated into SQL. Maybe this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35346630/creating-dynamic-expression-for-entity-framework

Comment: Is there a need to use a predicate? you can always just use && to archive the same statement in Linq. e.g Make a method that will return a bool and just plug it into the && clause.

Comment: It would be great to use predicate because version is not required so I decided to use predicate as above. It's strange because in other method which is similar it works correctly

Comment: Please read @RandRandom linked article. You must pass an expression (`Expression<Func<TEntity,TResult>>`) not a delegate (`Func<TEntity, TResult>`) for all `IQueryable<T>`. For `IEnumerable<T>` a delgate works too, because it does evaluates it in memory. But `IQueryable<T>` needs to be translated to SQL, so it must be an expression

Comment: Your error is coming from the brackets around the statement. It doesn't auto return without a return statement when you use the brackets.

Comment: You should consult the documentation for the difference. In a nutshell, an expression describes code but do not executes it (unless you compile the expression to a delegate and invoke it), but an delegate is already compiled

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQKit you can create predicates that will be expanded for you so you can use them in `IQueryable` expressions, but you don't need that for just excluding version testing.

```
var assocs = _context.Assoc
             .Where(x => x.Model == model);
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(version))
    assocs = assocs.Where(x.Version.Contains(version));
```

Answer (score -1):

becuse the EF can translate `Contains` method to sql (`Version LIKE '%@version%'`), but no evaluate your "external" function.

if you load the result to memroy (by export method as `ToList()`) you can do it as linq2object:

```
var assocs = _context.Assoc.ToList()
                .Where(x => x.Model == model)
                .Where(predicate);
```

My code shows and illustrates but it is definitely not recommended, because it is better to question the DB than to work on memory.

Comment: Why provide an answer that you dont recommend?

Comment: @RandRandom beacuse i think the question is **why**.

Comment: Shouldn't you at least put the `ToList` after the first `Where`?

Comment: The `ToList` here does nothing but prevent the first filter from being applied.  The second filter, not being an `Expression`, was never being provided to the query provider in the first place, and so the provider isn't going to fail to translate it (it's not even going to try).